# compile OpenMP program with ISPC compiler

Tags: c++, c, performance, openmp, intel

is it possible to compile OpenMP program with ISPC compiler ?

If yes, is performance more than compiling it with gcc ?

how can I use advantages of both ISPC and OpenMP ?

Answer (score 0):

After browsing through the [ISPC documentation](http://ispc.github.io/ispc.html), there doesn't appear to be any mention of OpenMP, and [this technical paper](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/ispc/ispc/ispc_inpar_2012.pdf) speaks of OpenMP and other parallelization frameworks in passing.

Remember though: the compiler targets a dialect of C and the language is focused on vectorization/SIMD, not processor level parallelism (SMP), although it would be pretty cool if it did also support OpenMP...

Comment: Yes it would be cool :). I did so and didnt find any sign of supporting openmp :(

Comment: The main program in C\C++ can easily use OpenMP constructs, the computation intensive functions can be written separately( to be compiled by by Ispc compiler) and called from within OpenMP loops or sections.